# Conducting a moderated multilevel mediation with more than two levels in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I'm trying to conduct a moderated multilevel mediation model in R, but I'm still a pretty junior graduate student and I've only ever done mediation with lavaan. My outcome variable is cortisol, for which I have two days' of cortisol data for each participant and five samples within each day (i.e., three levels necessary in my multilevel model). I tried running my analyses with lavaan, but quickly realized that the package couldn't run with more than two levels. Does anyone have a package recommendation that'll work?

Further details in case it's helpful: I'm making a path model to assess whether children's early internalization of their parents' care for them (attachment security at 12 months old) mediates the association between maternal sensitivity at 6 months old and diurnal cortisol slopes later in life (age ~40). My plan is to include the interaction between maternal sensitivity and time since awakening in predicting cortisol and the interaction between attachment security and time since awakening in predicting cortisol to get a sense of whether diurnal cortisol slope steepness varies depending on my other variables.

Thank you!

Comment: You might not get a good answer because this is a really advanced statistical method and a challenging research question laden with assumptions that requires a really strong foundation in causal inference and multilevel modeling. I personally would not expect a junior grad student, especially one with an applied focus, to be able to do this analysis at any time in their training. I would recommend collaborating with a methodologist who has experience with these models rather than trying to get help on CV. I wish you luck.

Comment: Did you try searching CrossValidated for 3-level SEM in R first?  The other "big" SEM package in R is `OpenMx`, so that's another keyword you can use to search.  I came up with this one (there might be more): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468457/multilevel-sem-with-three-or-more-levels-in-openmx