# Multilevel structural equation modeling with interaction between latent variables: designing the model and choosing the appropriate software

Tags: r, interaction, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

This has been a bit of a conundrum I've been trying to solve for a while and relates to a [question I asked a while ago](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/468457/283366).

I am trying to build a 4-level structural equation model (SEM) with latent interaction. It is still unclear to me how to best go about this. Seemingly, not many software packages are designed to do multilevel SEM (mSEM) or latent interaction, and one that are designed to do both is virtually non-existent.

So far, I've found two software packages that can do multilevel SEM:

- [LISREL](https://ssicentral.com/index.php/products/lisrel/) (any number of levels)
- [**OpenMx**](https://openmx.ssri.psu.edu) (R-package; any number of levels)
- [**M*plus***](https://www.statmodel.com) (limited to three levels)

With regards to performing analyses with latent interaction, there are a multitude of approaches to this, which can be divided into two categories: (1) using the products of indicators of the latent variables, or (2) distribution analytic approaches [(Marsh el al. 2012)](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2012-16551-026). While product indicator approaches, in principle, should be possible to perform by any SEM software, there are, according to [Umbach et al. (2017)](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/27496/Brandt_2017.pdf?sequence=1), only two software packages that can perform distribution analytic approaches:

- [**nlsem** (R-package)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlsem/nlsem.pdf) (can perform: QML, LMS, SEMM, NSEMM)
- [**M*plus***](https://www.statmodel.com) (can perform LMS, SEMM, NSEMM)

Preferentially, I've been looking for ways to perform analyses in R, since I already have developed a workflow there, and OpenMx, nlsem and M*plus* (through the *MplusAutomation*-package), seems to fulfill that requirement.

[Cortina et al. 2021](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2012-16551-026) recommended a six step process for conducting analyses on latent interaction, involving both product indicator and distribution analytic approaches. With this in mind the *nlsem* package seem tempting indeed. However, it is not capable of performing multilevel analyses. In this regard, OpenMx seem to be the most flexible, but is limited to product indicator approaches for latent interaction analyses. M*plus* seems to be the best compromise: it can by perform mSEM on up to three levels by design and can perform some distribution analytic latent interaction analyses (except QML).

It would seem like I can't both have the cake and eat it too, except I found [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21769/283366) citing to the article of [Muthén (1994)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0049124194022003006), which suggest it is possible to perform multilevel SEM with any software.

I am unsure what would be the best way to proceed:
Which software would be best to tackle the issue at hand? I can see the following alternatives:

1. I could use software that are designed for mSEM, such as OpenMx, using a product indicator approach for the latent interactions,
2. I could design a 4-level structural equation model according to [Muthén's (1994)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0049124194022003006) method and implement it in *nlsem*,
3. I could compromise and use M*plus*. I'd have to exclude one level in the analysis, and I won't be able to use QML (which I might not need anyway). M*plus* would additionally come with the advantage that it is well known and recognized, though it comes at a pretty hefty price tag.
4. I use a combination of the above.

What would your recommended course of action be? One one hand, alternative 1 and 3 seem pretty straightforward. On the other hand, alternative 2 or 4 might better achieve my what I want.  However,if I were to go for alternative 2 or 4, I could really use some advice on model design.

Comment: Possibly [JAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_another_Gibbs_sampler)?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the program, and I haven't really gotten into Bayesian statistics yet. From the link you sent, it doesn't seem to handle SEM though, or am I missing something?

Comment: Definitely in a Bayesian framework, but I think folks have done SEM with WinBUGS, so maybe able to do with JAGS also?

Comment: Stan is also possible, I believe.